# Potential problem with database stored over a server

Tags: vb.net

I am developing an application that runs on a network. It needs to contact to database (access database) very very often, which is stored in server. Around 30 Client computers contact the database almost every 2-3 seconds. I need to know could there be potential manifest problem in with the application?

Could there will be a problem if database is being updated by one client, at the same time other client contacts it?

Thanks a lot. With best regards, 
Furqan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Access does not perform well with more than approximately 5 - 10 concurrent connections.

Use [SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=220549b5-0b07-4448-8848-dcc397514b41) instead.

[SQL Server Express Edition Overview](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)

Have a look at the [SQL Server Migration Assistent](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/migration.aspx) from MS Access to SQL Server 2008

Comment: Thanks for your advise.  I really donot know how to create and access database in in SQL Server Express.  Could you give me a hint.

Comment: try this: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/ms-access-to-sql-database/

Answer (score 0):

It depends of course on the coding in your application. I have similar application running at work and have not experienced problems. The only thing you need to look out for is functions that require reading the database. So some tips might be handy.

First of all, try to limit the amount of time that the database connection is open (as Mitch pointed out).

Second, try to avoid large blocks of executable code between reading and saving queries. Don't read for example a maximum ID from your database, then run a code that needs more than 0.5 seconds to execute and then save a record that requires the maximum ID from the database. This could potentially go wrong if another user inserted a new item in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to SQL Express use blocks like this instead:

```
Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=" & servername & ";Database=" & databasename & ";User ID=" & userid & ";Password=" & password & ";Trusted_Connection=False;")

Dim sqlstatement As String = "INSERT INTO " & table & "  (ATime,AStringWithLimitedLength,AnInteger,AString)"
sqlstatement &= " VALUES (@dates,@chars,@ints,@string)"
Dim comm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstatement, conn)
With comm.Parameters
    .Add("@dates", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Me.Timestamp
    .Add("@chars", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.Type
    .Add("@ints", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Me.UserID
    .Add("@string", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Me.SQL
End With
conn.Open()
comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

All in all very similar to MSAccess, except that you don't use OleDB but SqlClient. You might want to download (for free) 'SQL Server Management Studio Express' to modify your database in a WYSIWYG way.